# Connect PC to laptop with android

Tags: connectify, file-sharing, android-pc

Is it possible to connect PC to laptop with Android phone to share files between PC and laptop? I don't have a LAN cable, all I have is:

A PC without WiFi adapter.
An Android USB cable. 
An Android phone. 
A laptop with built-in WiFi. 
Both PC and laptop have Windows 7.

What I'm trying to do is: 
1. Connect Android to PC with USB tethering. 
2. Then connect Android to laptop with WiFi tethering. 
3. Then I want to share files between PC and laptop.

I don't know much about networking stuff. 
Please tell me if you know.

Comment: I've set it up to use MTP (with USB) and also am running a ssh server on the phone. It is quite convenient to sync over ssh. Disclaimer: I don't know anything about Android.

Comment: What is mtp and ssh?

Comment: MTP is Media Transfer Protocol. And SSH is Secure Shell. Do a search for "mtp android". What is your OS/ distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way (IMO) is to bridge the network of USB tethering(192.168.42.x) and the Wifi hotspot(192.168.43.x), but I don't have any solution to bridge them.

That said, I do have a solution to transfer files between PC and Laptop within the constraints mentioned in the question (with "no internet" exclusively).

---

The common point of interaction in our current setting is the Android device itself, which means the device can access both systems, if required. If only I can access the content of Laptop as well as PC from Android, then using some File manager the data transfer can be done.

Note that I didn't try this method on Windows 7 but the instructions shouldn't be different for other platforms.

**Instructions**:

1. Connect PC to Android via USB tethering, and Laptop to Android via Wifi hotspot. Note down the IP address for both the machines.

   - Windows users see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/382265/fastest-method-to-determine-my-pcs-ip-address-windows) to know the IP address; click [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430853/how-do-i-find-my-internal-ip-address) Linux(Ubuntu) users for the same.
   - The IP address to be noted would be similar to **192.168.42.xyz** and **192.168.43.abc**, where **xyz** and **abc** are (+ve) integers, i.e. note the local IP address and not IP address from your ISP.
2. Setup an FTP server at both PC and Laptop.

   - Windows users see this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/85027/how-do-i-setup-an-ftp-server-on-windows-7), Linux(Ubuntu) users see these answers : [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323868/how-do-i-install-a-ftp-server), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17084/how-do-i-temporarily-run-an-ftp-server). I advise [Gadmin-Proftpd](http://mac.freecode.com/projects/gadmin-proftpd) for GUI in the latter platform.
   - While not necessary, run the server on port **21** (requires administrative/superuser privileges).
   - While configuring, create an FTP user for your FTP server. e.g. User: *u1* and Password:*password1*. Otherwise, if your program allows **anonymous** FTP session, then go ahead with it.
   - *Google is your friend in need, remember it since you might need it.*
3. Install a file manager in Android that can browse network storage. I recommend [ES File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop).
4. Launch [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop), swipe right from left edge to access **Network** → **FTP** → choose **ftp**.
5. For PC :

   - Fill IP address (from step 1) in **Server** field.
   - Leave port default to **21**.
   - Choose **Active** under **Mode**.
   - Fill **Username** and **Password** that you created in Step 2. If you selected anonymous in step 2 then choose **Anonymous** and leave the credentials fields blank.
   - Tap **OK**.

   For Laptop :

   - Repeat aforementioned steps for PC in this step with the exception of IP address and FTP credentials which has to be replaced with the ones for FTP server on Laptop.
6. If your FTP server is accessible and working fine, then [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) will create an entry with the name (probably) of local IP address of your PC/Laptop.
7. In FTP tab of [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop), select any entry and you'll be able to see the content of the running FTP server.
8. You can use cut-copy-paste-delete (subject to FTP server configuration) features of [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) on the content of these two network entries.

Done! :-)

---

<sup>Notes:</sup>

<sup>1. The data transfer speed is subjected to the resources available to Android.</sup>

<sup>2. You can run a server other than FTP. Make sure that server you decide can be mapped (supported) in a file manager in Android.</sup>

<sup>3. If your machine is running a firewall (most PC's either runs Windows Firewall, or an Antivirus does the same), then explicitly allow your FTP program to make and accept connections (it will be a great hassle if you don't). If it's feasible, temporarily disconnect both machines (disable Mobile data on Android as well) from Internet and disable firewall/Antivirus on both for that time being.</sup>

<sup>4. If your Android device is running a firewall (AFwall+ in my case), allow your file manger in it. It is something one might miss to do.</sup>

---

<sup>**Unsuccessful method with reason unknown as of now:**</sup>

<sup>1) I think the objective can be achieved by port forwarding at one interface. I found that the machine under USB-tethered network can access the wifi hotspot gateway (192.168.43.1) but could not ping a machine behind the latter. Vice versa wasn't true either. I planned to port-forward on hotspot interface so that a custom request to this
gateway IP address would be forwarded to a machine behind it. An e.g. would be: A Laptop connected to wifi hotspot is running a FTP server with IP address **192.168.43.32**. I then do  port-forwarding(Android rooted) as **192.168.43.1:21 → 192.168.43.32:21** i.e. the machine behind USB-tethered network with IP address **192.168.42.143** would be able to see **192.168.43.32:21** via **192.168.43.1:21**. Looks easy to me. But Port-forwarding apps on Play Store didn't yield satisfactory results. Let me know via comments if somebody tries this method and achieves success.</sup>

Comment: Yes!! That's good. It can solve my problem, i will surely try this and tell you.

Comment: @imassassin124 If the answer works for you, consider upvoting or accepting the answer, so that the other readers may benefit(trust) from it as well. Here, you can know more about this. http://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer :-)

Comment: Sorry i dont vote any of you because i dont have enough reputation :)

Comment: I've tried and it works hurray..., thanks again for the help and i create ftp server using filezilla server which is easy to use. It would be good if i access files directly on pc but still this also works great.

Comment: @imassassin124 Good to hear that it worked out. Would you mind telling me the data transfer speed you're getting? My device is kinda old, so the speed was around 200 KB/s. Kinda disappointing HW, I know. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you are using Cyanogenmod even without any 3rd party software:

Connect the phone to the PC and enable USB tethering. Then create a hotspot on your laptop and connect your phone to it.

After that, your phone shares it's WiFi connection to your PC, so you can transfer files and use internet.

If you're not a CM user then try using PdaNet+

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pdanet

Comment: I ve tried pdanet+ but that not work for me, but i haven't tried using cynogenmode.

Comment: @imassassin124 I'm using CM ROM and it actually works :)

Comment: Your idea is also good but it need root and installing rom, i will sure vote you up but I've low reputation. Anyway thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's not possible because Android will unmount the SD card (real or emulated) when plugged in via USB. This means that no apps on the phone will be able to read or write the SD card while the phone is plugged in, including whatever WiFi tethering app you're using.

If both laptop and desktop have Bluetooth, you might be able to send files through Bluetooth from laptop to phone to desktop or vice versa, which would be fairly painless.

If there's no other way you could always plug the phone into the laptop, transfer files onto the phone, then plug into the desktop and transfer files off the phone; it's awkward, but it works.

Comment: I m doing usb tether, it does not unmount my sd !

Comment: UMS will prevent the Android device from accessing the SD card, but MTP will not.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, its simple. Create a gmail account and use google cloud drive. Put all files that you need there , open your laptop go to your gmail account and download your files .

Comment: OP can't access the internet on his desktop, so he can't access Google.