# Play videos from another android device over wifi

Tags: wi-fi, video, wifi-tethering, wifi-direct

Is there a way to play videos over a wifi connection (tethering/direct)? I'm using a Nexus 9 which is lacking a SD card slot. Therefore I want to play videos from my Android phone which has enough space. As I need it for my vacation it should be an offline solution. The solutions I have found only providing copying the files from one device to another (Airdroid,Xender,Droid over wifi). Is there any streaming/direct access solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run an FTP or HTTP server on your Android device which has bigger storage. There are many apps on Play Store which can create a server on Android like [FTP Server Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.ftpserverultimate) or [Servers Ultimate Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimatepro).  Creating a server on them is very easy. You can get an idea from [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/106323/96277) as well (see **#Method 3**).
2. Install a file manager which allows access to remote storage such as [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) or [MiXplorer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1523691). Both are very intuitive and can create an FTP server or either access it. (See *step 5* [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/108997/96277) for former's usage.)

   It goes without saying that both devices need to be connected under same Wi-Fi or hotspot.
3. Install a multimedia player such as [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en) to stream videos.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

A more user-friendly solution might be to use [AllCast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.cast) together with the [AllCast Receiver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.cast.receiver).

AllCast allows you to *cast* your media from one device to another. Usually, it's used for casting to streaming devices like the Chromecast and Smart TVs, but if you install the [AllCast Receiver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.cast.receiver), you can also cast from one Android device to another.

As with running a HTTP server, both devices do need to be connected to the same WiFi network.